# Longest and Shortest word in a file C programming

Tags: c

Hello and good evening,

So i'm writing a program in C, that will accept a file.txt as an input and read the text.  The program should read the text file, find the longest and shortest word within the file, and print them out when it reaches the end.

I'm REALLY close but i'm getting a seg fault and, not only do I not know why, but i'm at a loss as to how to fix it.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *fp;
char str[60];
char *largest;
char *smallest;
char *word;
int i, j;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

// check that there are only two arguments
if (argc == 2) {
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
}
// if not throw this error
else {
    perror("Argument error.");
    return (-1);
}
// check if the file exists
if  (fp == NULL) {
    perror("Error opening file.");
    return (-1);
}

// set largest to first string and smallest to second
largest = strcpy(largest, strtok(str, " "));
smallest = strcpy(smallest, strtok(NULL, " "));
word = strcpy(word, strtok(str, " "));

// while we get lines of the file
while (fgets (str, 60, fp) != NULL) {
    // while the token string isn't empty
    while (word != NULL) {
        if (strlen(largest) > strlen(word)) {
            strcpy(word, largest);
        }
        if (strlen(smallest) < strlen(word)) {
            strcpy(word, smallest);
        }
    }
}
printf("The largest word in the file is: %s", largest);
printf("The smallest word in the file is: %s", smallest);

fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure it's the second while loop...I don't want to use it anyway, but i've been hacking at this for so long it's all my logic can think of.

Any help would be appreciated.  This IS homework, though only a small part of it, and i'm not asking for helping solving the entire problem.

Also, there is a Makefile involved...I don't think it's important post but feel free to ask me and i'll update.

As I built this I can confirm that the file is able to read and I can print, put, and do all kinds of cool things.  It only broke when I tried to implement my logic for longest/shortest word.

Thanks!

Comment: `char *largest;... strcpy(largest, strtok(str, " "));` --> `largest` is not initialized nor assigned.  `stcpy()` is then UB.

Comment: Likely unrelated to your seg fault.. but I think you're missing a `}` after line 18 :) looks like you've edited it now

Comment: Also:  doesnt this line of code :if (strlen(largest) > strlen(word)) {
            strcpy(largest, word);
Say "if the length of largest is greater than the length of word then copy largest to word"  ? 
Isn't the idea for largest to be the largest word.
Shouldn't it be : "If the length of largest is less then the length of word then assign the value of word to largest"

Comment: Chux, Barney, and David:

Made the suggested changes because, well, you're right lol.  

Still a seg fault though.  Perhaps I need to take a walk or something.

Comment: What line is causing the seg fault? Did you step through it with the debugger?

Comment: It's using linux and I don't have gdp installed on it.  

I'm fairly certain it's this:

    while(word != NULL)

The second while loop.

Comment: The condition of the `while` loop is definitely not causing a seg fault. Segmentation faults are caused by accessing memory incorrectly. If you can't use a debugger, one thing you can do is put output statements on each line of the code and see how many are output before the error occurs.

Comment: @d512  Seg faults only happen around anything having to do with largest/smallest/word past the initialization.

I've deduced this from commenting out parts of the code.  It runs perfectly when all instances of largest/smallest and word are not a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your logic. Try the below code

Few assumptions I made are,

Maximum word length is 20 characters. You can change it by MAX_WORD_LENGTH macro.
Words in file are space separated
Max line length is 60 characters

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 20

int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
    FILE *fp;
    char str[60];
    char *largest = (char*) malloc (MAX_WORD_LENGTH);
    char *smallest = (char*) malloc (MAX_WORD_LENGTH);
    int smallest_len = MAX_WORD_LENGTH, largest_len = 0;

    if (argc == 2) 
    {
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Argument error.");
        return (-1);
    }

    if  (fp == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Error opening file.");
        return (-1);
    }

    while (fgets (str, 60, fp) != NULL) 
    {
        char *temp = strtok(str, " ");
        while (temp != NULL) 
        {
            if (strlen(temp) > largest_len) 
            {
                strcpy(largest, temp);
                largest_len = strlen(largest);
            }
            if (strlen(temp) < smallest_len) 
            {
                strcpy(smallest, temp);
                smallest_len = strlen(smallest);
            }
            temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }

    printf("The largest word in the file is: %s\n", largest);
    printf("The smallest word in the file is: %s\n", smallest);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works but, if I may ask a question:

Why do you have to malloc when you're using strtok?

Comment: The code is copying the token returned by strtok to "smallest" and "largest" character points. You need to allocate memory to "smallest" and "largest"  before doing strcpy.
You might get segmentation fault without that. Try and see.

Comment: I did try that because I was curious.  Spot on advice.  

In my head I was thinking I didn't need to malloc with strtok and, in a way, i was right, but if I want to do store the information I need then i'll need to ask the system for memory.

Yay C programming.....

Answer (score 0):

So I just ran this online and it looks like the seg fault is caused by the line

```
largest = strcpy(largest, strtok(str, " "));
```

This is because `largest` is the destination of the string copy in the call

```
strcpy(largest, strtok(str, " "));
```

but it's a pointer that points to nothing. It should be declared as an actual array like this:

```
char largest[60];
```

Also, you shouldn't be calling `strtok` on a `str` when it hasn't been initialized to anything. It's not even a proper string so there's no way `strtok` is going to do anything useful at that point.

Comment: But how?  strtok(str, " ") should return the first token...which is a string.

Any idea?

Comment: Oh...that makes sense.  It's been initialized but it's not a thing because we haven't actually read the file yet.

Meh...2 hours on this man...

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track now. Here's a thought: instead of trying to initialize `largest` and `smallest` to the first words in the file, maybe you can set `largest` to something really small like an empty string and `smallest` to something really big like 61 spaces (each line in the file is 60 chars long so you know that's bigger than any single token you'll find). That might simplify things for you.

Comment: That is....a great idea that I didn't even consider. 

I'll give it a shot and then shoot this thread a notice.  Thanks!

Comment: It wasn't me.  I'm in the middle of testing still.

Comment: Marking the answer as correct because it answers my direct question.

That is exactly why I was getting a seg fault and your awesome suggestion is getting me results.

It's also showing that my logic in the second while loop may be wrong because it's printing " " for largest and alsdkfjalsdjfalsdff for the smallest.

There's no comparing going down...which sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Adopt it for your needs with argv[2]

and enjoy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const int max_word_length = 60;
    char longest[max_word_length];
    char shortest[max_word_length];
    char current[max_word_length];

    size_t longest_length = 0;
    size_t shortest_length = max_word_length;
    size_t current_length = 0;

    freopen("input", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output", "w", stdout);

    while (scanf("%s", current) > 0) {
        current_length = strlen(current);
        if ( current_length > longest_length) {
            longest_length = current_length;
            strcpy(longest, current);
        }

        if (current_length < shortest_length) {
            shortest_length = current_length;
            strcpy(shortest, current);
        }
    }


    printf("%s %s", shortest, longest);

    return 0;
}
```