# find longest string in a file with linux kernel function and write in second file

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

hi i want to Write a command that reads a string from a file using the Linux kernel functions, and then writes the string with the largest length in the second file./ its in c /
But I have a problem with the fact that first, the program takes the string from the input, not from the file that is in the system, and the second is that it displays the output instead of the second file.
I did a lot of work but I could not do it if you can correct the code for me

```
/* Trivial file copy program using low-level I/O */

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BSIZE 16384
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


void main()
{
  int fin, fout; /* Input and output handles */
  char buf[BSIZE];
  int count;

  if ((fin  = open("foo", O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
    perror("foo");
    exit(1);
  }
  if ((fout = open("bar", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644)) < 0) {
    perror("bar");
    exit(2);
  }
  while ((count = read(fin, buf, BSIZE)) > 0)
  {
    char string[100], word[20], max[20], min[20], c;
    int i = 0, j = 0, flag = 0;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    i = 0;
    do
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        c = getchar();
        string[i++] = c;

    } while (c != '\n');
    string[i - 1] = '\0';
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
    {
        while (i < strlen(string) && !isspace(string[i]) && isalnum(string[i]))
        {
            word[j++] = string[i++];
        }
        if (j != 0)
        {
            word[j] = '\0';
            if (!flag)
            {
                flag = !flag;
                strcpy(max, word);
                strcpy(min, word);
            }
            if (strlen(word) > strlen(max))
            {
                strcpy(max, word);
            }
            if (strlen(word) < strlen(min))
            {
                strcpy(min, word);
            }
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("The largest word is '%s' and smallest word is '%s' in '%s'.\n", max, min, string);

    return 0;
    }

    write(fout, buf, count);

  close(fin);
  close(fout);
}
```

Comment: Did you try File I/O in C? Try that!

Comment: You are reading line using " c = getchar();" which of cause is from input not from file. and after finding largest writing to file using "write(fout, buf, count);". Try to open the file from which you need to take the input and read from that. May be this can help https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm

Comment: you have lots of issue in your code. one of them is flush(stdin) is UB. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268733/longest-and-shortest-word-in-a-file-c-programming this might give some idea.

Comment: Hasn't this been asked already a few hours ago?

Comment: What's the `Enter string` prompt for?  You're reading from a file and don't need input from the user.

Comment: Use a function able to read a full line, not a bunch of raw chars. fgets?

Comment: regardless of what some ancient compilers (like visual studio) will allow, there are only two valid signatures for the `main()` function.  Both of those signatures have a return type of `int`, not `void`

Comment: regardless of what `visual studio` will allow, this statement; `fflush( stdin );` is (in the C standard) specifically stated as 'undefined behavior'.  The function `fflush()` is ONLY for output streams, not input streams

Comment: the posted code is trying doing WHAT exactly?  The posted code has nothing to do with the text of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here, but you're basically reading from standard input when you shouldn't be. In fact more than half of that code is unnecessary.

I have a small example here, that sticks to the wording of your original question and at least shows what part of the code needs cutting:

```
/* Find the longest word in a text file (foo) and write that word out to another file (bar) */
/* A word is a group of characters delimited by white space */
/* A word is shorter than 16384 characters */
/* We are trying to use low-level system functions (e.g. open, close, read, write) */
/* instead of standard library functions (e.g. fopen, fclose, fread, fwrite) */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BSIZE 16384

/* read a single word from a file */
static int read_word(int fd, char *buf)
{
    int i = 0;
    char c = 0;
    int bytes = read(fd, &c, 1);        /* extract a single character */
    while (isspace(c) && bytes != 0)    /* skip whitespace */
        bytes = read(fd, &c, 1);
    while (!isspace(c) && bytes != 0) {
        buf[i++] = c;            /* store character */
        bytes = read(fd, &c, 1);
    }

    return i;                /* return number of characters read */
}

int  main()
{
    int fin = open("foo", O_RDONLY);
    if (fin < 0) {
        perror("foo");
        exit(1);
    }

    int fout = open("bar", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
    if (fout < 0) {
        perror("bar");
        exit(2);
    }

    char buf[BSIZE] = {0};
    char largest[BSIZE] = {0};

    int bytes = 0;
    int count = 0;
    do {
        bytes = read_word(fin, buf);            /* read next word */
        if (bytes > count) {
            strncpy(largest, buf, BSIZE - 1);    /* preserve largest word seen so far */
            count = bytes;
        }

        memset(buf, 0, BSIZE);
    } while (bytes > 0);

    write(fout, largest, count);                /* write largest word to file */
    close(fin);
    close(fout);
    printf ("\nLargest word found was %s @ %d characters length.\n", largest, count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much